# Simple series question. $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{((n^5)+1)^\frac{1}{3}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I think this converges due to direct comparison with $\frac{1}{n^{5/3}}$ but I can't double check this anywhere.

Comment: You're on the right track. What exactly does the direct comparison test say, and how can you prove it's true that $a_n \leq b_n$

Comment: I thought that considering there was a plus 1 in the denominator of the problem question it would always be smaller than 1/n^5/3 so since 1/n^5/3 converges due to the p-test and is bigger than a similar smaller function know that the smaller converges as well do to direct comparison. Do you agree?

Comment: You're exactly right.

Answer (score 2):

Right.

$(n^5+1)^{1/3}
\gt (n^5)^{1/3}
=n^{5/3}
$

so the sum converges by the $p$-test:

$\sum \dfrac1{n^p}$
converges for
$p > 1$
(easily proved by the
integral test)
and diverges for
$p \le 1$.